# Solana-keygen grind - public address cannot end with "I" (InvalidCharacter)

Tags: publickey, solana-keygen, vanity-id

I'm using `solana-keygen` utility to `grind` for a public key with specific traits.
Currently my input was as follows:

```
solana-keygen grind --ends-with I:1
```

however, I get this error:

```
error: Invalid value "I:1" for '--ends-with <SUFFIX:COUNT>': I: InvalidCharacter { character: 'I', index: 0 }
```

for lower-case "i", this error does not appear.

Why is upper-case "I" not allowed as suffix of public key?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solana addresses are represented in Base58 encoding. Base58 encoding is a modified version of Base64 encoding and made popular by Bitcoin.

As compared to Base64, it removes 6 characters which may cause confusion due to the similar look i.e. capital i [I], lowercase L [l], capital o [O], zero [0], plus [+] and slash [/]. This is done to remove any kind of ambiguity because addresses are a sensitive information and even single character if typed mistakenly can lead to the permanent loss of the funds.